# My game crashed... Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Tags: unity, c#, loading

I guess this is the first official crash I've had in Unity (that is not just an infinite loop.) The game works just fine in the editor but when build and run it, the game won't even start.

I just keep getting this error message:

[image]

So I check the folder specified but I have no idea what I'm looking at if I'm completely honest with my self. I see a bunch of directories and stuff but that's about it. I don't know how to read an error log but I'd like to. This whole game is a learning experience so I would to learn how but Idk what to do.

this is the error log : [Here](http://ryanmhenry1995.weebly.com/uploads/5/6/5/1/56519861/error.log)

If need be I'll put it in the question but I'd like to avoid making this too long. If you have any questions about my code you need to know let me know.

Comment: Try turning off your Anti virus temporarily. Live protection messes up with things.

Comment: Did you try this? http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/951281/view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing... I had some compiler errors showing up in the editor from me converting some game Objects to transforms. I changed them back to gameObjects and everything works fine. I was just trying to save a little memory. but thank you guys for your advise down in the comments.

Comment: Do you mean you tried to explicitly cast GameObjects as Transform like this : `GameObject obj=(Transform) obj2` ? where obj2 is another game object. Asking because may be you need transform, but don't know how to access it.

Comment: I had a ton of game Object variables that only ever referenced transforms. but now I've made a system too complex to just turn them all into transform variables.

Answer (score 11):

I see you solved your own problem. However, I would like to explain what are you looking at, and what to look for in an error log like the one you received, in case you get a similar error in the future.

There are many type of error logs, and this one is quite low level. It is difficult to understand what the problem is with a large game with such an error log, but there are some clues you may use to help yourself.

The first line is the Unity Player version. This is relatively important, as an error may be linked to a precise version of the player that you're using. In general, always try to make sure you're using the last version of Unity to make your games.

Then you get the error type and location. In this case, the error is:

```
test 8.exe caused an Access Violation (0xc0000005)
  in module test 8.exe at 0023:01275744.
```

In here, you can see that the error is an access violation, which corresponds to code `0xc0000005`. Regardless of the error code, it might be useful to search online for it, and that way you can at least know whether or not the error is related to your program or not.

In this case, in Windows, error `0xc0000005` may be related to closing handles that are currently in use, that is, you're using a handle in one thread and you're closing it in another at the same time. If you're not doing anything like this, then it is likely that this is an error in the player itself.

Then you see the module that caused the error, and the program location. In this case, the module is `8.exe`, which is the same executable file. It is perfectly possible that the error was not caused in the executable file, but in a DLL that you loaded.

The next section is some general information regarding to the state of the machine when the error happened:

```
Error occurred at 2015-11-01_000136.
D:\..........\8.exe, run by Foo.
32% memory in use.
0 MB physical memory [0 MB free].
0 MB paging file [0 MB free].
0 MB user address space [3746 MB free].
Read from location 7220799c caused an access violation.
```

If you see something like "100% memory in use", you may want to think that the problem was caused by filling up the memory.

Also, you can see that the actual error happened when trying to read from memory location `7220799c`. This seems to be a normal memory location, but if the conflicting address was `00000000` or something like that, then the problem is a null pointer access.

Then you see the runtime context. This contains the CPU registers, the bytes at CS:EIP and the stack. These are snapshots of several parts of the computer at the exact moment the program crashed.

First you get the CPU registers. Unless you have a disassembly of the program, it's very difficult to diagnose something like this, but if you see EIP (Instruction Pointer) set to 0, then it probably means you're calling a null pointer. Also, if EBP (Base Pointer) and ESP (Stack Pointer) are vastly different, then it probably means you had a stack overflow.

Then, you get the bytes at `CS:EIP`. This is what the instruction pointer is pointing to. This is the actual program code that was meant to be executed. Not much to see here, but you may want to [decode the actual bytes](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html) and see what the actual instruction is about. In this case, `f3 0f` is a "Shift Packed Data Left Logical" MMX or SSE2 instruction. If you see something like pure zeroes or pure `f`s in here, then it probably means you're executing invalid code. Check the value of `EIP` in the context above.

Then you get the stack. The currently active stack frame is what you have from `EBP` to `ESP`. In this case, there is not much to see here, but if for example, you see a truncated large text in there, then it is possible that you are experiencing a stack overrun.

Finally, you get a list of the modules that are loaded into memory with your program. Look at this list to find DLLs that you are not expecting (like viruses, or antiviruses), or old versions of DLLs that you are expecting.

Answer (score -1):

I have had something like that for 2 months. I solved it myself.

Try do download new graphic card drivers from nvidia or ati, then use software called Display Driver uninstaller, uninstall all your graphic card drivers then restart PC, install new ones and restart again.

It is possible that you had more than 1 card drivers installed because u recently changed hardware or something.

My rust is fine now :)
I hope it helps